# PHP mail line break problem

Tags: php, formatting, email, format

I want to format content of the mail to show the content in different line.
here is my message contetn.
bu the \n and \r is not working in this case. it just shows all the content in one line.

```
$message = 'Thank you for using . We really appreciate your business.'."\r\n".'If you are making your payment by mail, please make the check out to "blah blah" and send it to:'."\n".'blah blah '."\n".'blah blah'."\n".'San Gabriel, CA 91776'."\n".'Please see the attached invoice in PDF format for easy saving & printing purposes.';

$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));
$headers = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
$headers .= "--".$separator."--";
mail($_POST['add6'],$subject, $message, $headers);
```

how can i do that?

Comment: Show us how you are sending the mail. I suspect you might be providing headers to tell the client it's an HTML mail, so the CR LF gets treated like any other whitespace.

Comment: as pointed by Paul depending the content type of the mail the line feed could be ignored .... so can you post the whole block of code include headers

Comment: i have added my code snippet pls see that and give a suggestion!!

Comment: so yes sunce your Content-Type is text/html, it's normal the \n\r are voided, you should use proper html so <br/> or <p></p>

Comment: what's in your $eol var?

Comment: and if it is EOL, why to use ti twice per line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're telling the email client the message is HTML, so the CR LF combination will be treated like any other whitespace.

To fix this, change the content type to show you are sending a plain text email

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
```

Alternatively, turn your message into an HTML message - an easy way to do that in your case would be to run it through [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br) to turn the newlines into `<br>` tags

Comment: Actually - are you sure it's not? Can't find any reference to `text/plaint`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Content-Type: text/plain; no ?

Comment: Good catch. I did that mistake too which took me a while to find out :)

Answer (score 5):

Yep you've got `Content-Type: text/html`, so the CR LF is being treated like whitespace. Either send it as `Content-Type: text/plain` or call [`nl2br`](http://us.php.net/nl2br) on your contents.

Answer (score 2):

Your content type is HTML so you should use br or p tags instead of line feeds

Answer (score 0):

For \n to work it needs to be double quotes, not single. "\n" is the right thing, '\n' is wrong and will not work.